# How much electricity is needed to run a magnetoplasmadynamic thruster?

Tags: magnetoplasmadynamic, plasma

I am making a small [Magnetoplasmadynamic thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoplasmadynamic_thruster) (MPT) which uses compressed air as propellant. I want to know how many volts of electricity would be needed such that the exhaust plasma velocity is around 50 to 100m/s? What apparatus would I need to generate the high voltage at home?

Comment: To make a useful plasma *at atmospheric pressure* would require absurdly dangerous amounts of current and voltage. It's not something you can safely do at home. *Lightning* is a good example of a plasma at atmospheric pressure! Electric shock, X-ray radiation exposure, thermal burns, ozone poisoning, nitrogen oxide poisoning, yuck! This kind of engine is meant to work at very low ambient pressure and high power.

Comment: Also, for a plasma velocity of 100m/s (360 km/h) you may as well just use compressed air!